# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button with a click function like below:

```
$('.toggler').click(function() {
  var id = $('.song-top > div').data('track-id');
  var wid = 'width'+id;
  var wav = 'wavesurfer'+id;
  wid = $(this).width();
  wav.drawer.containerWidth = wav.drawer.container.clientWidth;
  wav.drawBuffer();  
});
```

Using JQuery 2.1.3 `var id` returns correctly a number, so why I get this error from console?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined

However if I manually set the `id` number it works:

```
$('.toggler').click(function() {
  width268 = $(this).width();
  wavesurfer268.drawer.containerWidth = wavesurfer268.drawer.container.clientWidth;
  wavesurfer268.drawBuffer();  
});
```

Comment: where have you defined `container` and `wav`?

Comment: `wav` is being assigned a string, it's not an object?

Comment: You have `var wav = 'wavesurfer'+id;` and then you have `wav.drawer.containerWidth =...` Have you added a `drawer` property to `String.prototype`? Because `wav` refers to a string.

Comment: @BenM yes it's an object... that is my fault

Comment: Then that explains your error, you're overwriting it inside the callback (see my answer).

Comment: Having something named `wavesurfer268` doesn’t seem like a good idea. Where does it come from?

Comment: @Ryan I'm using Wavesurfer JS plugin to generate waveforms on my page.

Comment: @NineCattoRules: Okay, but what creates `wavesurfer268` specifically? Do you have a bunch of `<script>var wavesurfer{{ i }} = …</script>` in a template or something?

Comment: @Ryan yes I set for each waveform a new wavesurfer object inline (I believe there is a more elegant approach but my JS knowledge is as novice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're overwriting `wav` inside the callback:

```
$('.toggler').click(function() {
  var id = $('.song-top > div').data('track-id');
  var wid = 'width'+id;
  var wav = 'wavesurfer'+id; // <--- overwrite??
  wid = $(this).width();
  wav.drawer.containerWidth = wav.drawer.container.clientWidth;
  wav.drawBuffer();  
});
```

I guess you need to change the name of the variable to `wave` or something else that's distinct. If you actually want to assign the `wavesurfer1` object to be `wav`, you can use the following (assuming that your `wavesurfer1` object is in `window` scope):

```
var wav = window['wavsurfer'+id];
```

Comment: is there any chance to set an object like  `wavesurfer` + my `id`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You wish to assign `wav` an object based on the dynamic name you're creating here?

Answer (score 1):

your variable `wav` is not a complex object, it's a string, as declared in the following line:

```
var wav = 'wavesurfer'+id;
```

you are trying to access a property called `drawer` out of your string, but it does not exist, so `drawer` is `undefined`. when you try to use `drawer.container`, your `drawer` is `undefined`, so that exception is raised.

on the piece of code you said it is working, you're using a different object, `wavesurfer268`, which probably has the correct properties.

Comment: you can't say that "wavesurfer268" is a string based on the OP post, it's not declared or overwritten there. So, I assumed it's a complex object

Comment: Great! But it might also be worth noting the difference between `null` and `undefined` (they're pretty big in JS!)

Comment: we need more of your code to help with that. how does the object "wavesurfer268" is set?

Comment: you can't create dynamic variables in javascript. I guess you are trying to create an object called "wavesurfer" + ID, but that will just return you a string, not an object

Comment: @Stormhashe Yes you can. `window['wavesurfer'+id];` (assuming `window` scope, of course).

Comment: I mean, I think he's trying to declare variables on the fly, like the waversufer268

Comment: No, I assume that `wavesurfer268` has already been defined, te OP just wants to reference it based on `track-id`

Comment: you assume correcly for ID 268, but he's passing the ID as a variable, so it could be anything. from that point of view, I assumed he's trying to use variables created on the fly